# Cant insert pins on map from Firebase database - XAML

Tags: c#, google-maps, xaml, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins) article to populate my map with pins.

I have the following code to display pins from my firebase database in a Xamarin.Forms.Maps

PageMap.xaml.cs:

```
            public PageMap()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                BindingContext = this;
    
                databaseLoad();
    
            }
    
            public ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord> DatabaseItems { get; set; } = new
      ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord>();
    
            FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("firebaselink");
    
    
            private void databaseLoad()
            {
                var collection = firebaseClient
                    .Child("Localizacoes")
                    .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
                    .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
                    {
                        if (dbevent != null)
                        {
                            DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
                        }
                    });
            }
```

PageMap.xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <maps:Map x:Name="map"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseItems}">
            <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maps:Pin Position="{Binding Position}"
                              Address="{Binding Address}"
                              Label="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        </maps:Map>
</Grid>
```

(EDIT) MyDatabaseRecord.Cs:

```
public class MyDatabaseRecord
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }

}
```

And my database looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmFyC.png)

My problem here is that, the pin is generated with the right address and description, but the position returns as 0,0 instead of the one present on the database.

What changes can I make for it to work? Thanks in advance

Comment: your database is storing Position as a single string, where the map expects a Position that consists of two doubles for Lat and Long

Comment: So, in terms of database it's best if I separate them as different double values? But then how can I change my code for it to work? @Jason

Comment: yes, the db should store them as discrete values.  The `Position` property in your model should return an object of type `Position` with the Lat and Long values set appropriately

Comment: @Jason But how do I push both values (Lat / Long) to the Position field since I'm using {Binding ...} ?

Comment: create a property that builds a Position from the lat/long values in the string.  You haven't provided any code for your model so it's difficult to provide a more concrete answer

Comment: @Jason Just edited it, hope it can provide more info for you to help me

Comment: if Position is stored in your db as a single string, then you need to have a corresponding string property in your class, otherwise that data will be lost when you query it from Firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this to dynamically create the position object from your string

```
public class MyDatabaseRecord
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    
    private Position parsedPosition;

    public Position ParsedPosition { 
      get {
         if (parsedPosition != null) return parsedPosition;

         var pos = Position.Split(',');
         double lat = double.Parse(pos[0]);
         double lng = double.Parse(pos[1]);
         parsedPosition = new Position(lat,lng);
         return parsedPosition;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still returns me the pin as (0,0) on the map

Comment: did you update your binding to use `ParsedPosition`?  Have you debugged `ParsedPosition` to verify it is correctly parsing the string?

Comment: Yes I updated, it returns me "Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position" instead of the coordinates

Comment: What about the 2nd part of my question?

Comment: I added {get; set;} at the end of private Position parsedPosition and it fixed it. It shows perfectly now